# Scroll to with custom CSS3 transition

Tags: jquery, css, scrollto

I have a piece of code that uses standard jQuery powered animation to scroll smoothly from one part of a page to another (to avoid the disorientating page jump for in page anchors). Here it is:

```
// Scroll to 
$('.scrollto').click(function() {
   var elementClicked = $(this).attr("href");
   var destination = $(elementClicked).offset().top;
   $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, 800 );
   return false;
});
```

Instead of using JQuery's animation I'd like to use a custom CSS3 transition as follows:

```
.scrollto {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.77,0,.175,1);
     -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.77,0,.175,1);
      -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.77,0,.175,1);
          transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.77,0,.175,1);
}
```

How can I merge the two together and make sure CSS3 transitions are used instead of jquery's?

Comment: Doubtful, I'm not sure how the whole page would animate. Perhaps you need an easing' plugin like [**JqueryUI/Easing**](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) or Special Easing in the animate property [**Jquery Animate**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: this https://github.com/rdallasgray/bez allows you to use bezier curves in jquery animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use CSS3 transitions to control a jQuery function. Nor can you use CSS to animate the scroll bar directly because scroll position is not a style.

There are libraries that simulate scrolling by leveraging CSS3 transformations ([iScrollJS for example](http://iscrolljs.com/)), but in order to move the native scroll bar, you'll need to use strictly JavaScript.

The solution is to use the [jQuery Easing library](https://jqueryui.com/easing/) which allows for custom easing functions. It also comes with replicas of the built in CSS3 easing functions as well.

Comment: I see reversed logic twice here... jQuery would (hypothetically) control initiating the transitions - and it's easing functions have been around quite a bit longer.

Comment: There's no way to animate the scroll bar in CSS. There are libraries that leverage CSS3 transformations that give the appearance of scrolling, but in order to animate scrollTop (as is being requested), you need to do it in JavaScript

Comment: With that I must concur (matter of fact, why not put it in the answer).

Comment: Great idea. I've further clarified the answer.

Comment: Thats a shame but it makes sense now you explain it. I appreciate your efforts to get as close to what I want as possible.